# Statewide (and more) Address Point data source

Tags: data, address, commercial

I am seeking a data source for a statewide address point layer. I do not need resident or business information at these addresses; I just need the validated structured addresses (preferably with standardized elements) and the coordinate.

This is for an address suggestion application on clients without internet access. We could do server side queries to an internet service, but not client side. (So, for example, this is why we cannot use Google for queries.) We will be querying *partial* addresses to build suggestions, so generally geocode services will not work. Partial addresses will have a zip code.

Ideally though, we would obtain a database of address points, allowing a partioned table query server side against that database.

The main State we want is Missouri, followed by Illinois, but could go as high as a nationwide database. We have interest at this time in countries other than the United States.

Do not worry about budget issues on this. I need to gather information on available sources before working up a budget/RFP.

Comment: You are going to have a very hard time doing this; as I don't think there is a single state right now that has a comprehensive list of both addresses and a geocoder process to resolve to all those addresses. The biggest issue is resolution of data from all counties in a state for all permutations. I am working on a project like this for my state (WA) and find that the sources of data and the quality of the resolution differ. Going between Parcels, TomTom and Tiger and any other source is a huge stuggle. Even vendors don't have a 100% coverage, if they say they do; then you need to suspect.

Answer (score 1):

[Navteq](http://www.nn4d.com/site/global/learn/basics_of_map_data/10_coremap.jsp) supply us with point addresses data for Australia, and supply the same for many other countries (US included).
It's not tremendously cheap, but *is* thorough, vetted, and updated quarterly.
They provide the data in several different formats, from shapemaps through to generic RDBM-format.
I understand Navteq get their data from the same guys that Google use for google maps.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two more resources:

ReportAll has a fair coverage nationally of parcel data, which you could find the address info from (not free).

http://reportallusa.com/products/parlay/

OGRIP supplies LBRS point address data for most of the counties within Ohio (free).

http://gis1.oit.ohio.gov/geodatadownload/lbrs.aspx

Answer (score 1):

While there are still large areas of empty space (2014), the [OpenAddresses](http://openaddresses.io/) (also on GitHub [here](https://github.com/openaddresses/openaddresses)) database may be one to watch in the future.  The database has been seeing steady increases of datasets, especially in the larger US metro areas.

Some key highlights (as stated on the website):

- CC0 Licensed. Address files licensed individually. Download the raw files. Or download the processed files.
- Parse them, import them into a database, or put them on a map or use them for geocoding. The choice is yours!
- Help grow OpenAddresses and submit an address file. Or add an address file directly through Github.

The [US Open Data Initiative](https://usodi.org/) is even [offering a bounty](https://usodi.org/2014/08/01/openaddresses/) for each new United States municipality that’s added from August 1, 2014 through September 30, 2014.