# Get house addresses within polygon?

Tags: data, united-states, reverse-geocoding

Is there a data source/service for the USA where, if we provide a polygon, it provides the addresses of all houses contained within it? I just want to know if this type of functionality or similar to this exist?

Comment: I dont know exactly. But you can look for if any option available in `Advance digitizing` Toolbar in Qgis 2.2+.

Comment: Related or possible duplicate: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15446/statewide-and-more-address-point-data-source/15591#15591